# Windows File Explorer Item Spacing

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is it possible to change the item spacing in 'small icons' view in the file explorer in Windows 10?

Basically before the creator's update I used to have 5 columns of items while in this view, but now after the update it seems that spacing between items has been increased slightly and now i only have 4 columns instead of 5.

So I would like to know if there is some option to set the item spacing in this view